# how do I stop from rendering a file on a specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a footer that renders in the entire application. I will like to prevent that to happen in a specific page.

```
= render "layouts/footer"
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application controller set a boolean variable to true then in your application.html file

In your application_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_value

def set_value
  @value = true
end
```

In your applicaion.html.erb file

```
<% if @value%>  
   <%= render "layouts/footer" %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your spacific pages actions set this value to false so that the footer will not be rendered.

```
def some_action
  @value = false
end
```